# P&T Contact Form plugin : how can I dynamically add multiple email recipients inside the form config file?

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-contactform

I don't want to show up the email recipients in the source code using this :

```
<input type="hidden" name="toEmail" value="{{ 'me@example.com,me2@example.com'|hash }}">
```

I want to manage multiple emails dynamically from the contactform.php config file in my craft/config folder.

```
<?php

return array(
    'toEmail' => (hash('firstemail@domain.com, secondemail@domain.com') ?: null),
);
```

This config file is not working and don't override the plugin settings in the CP. What would be the best way to achieve this ?

**[UPDATE]**

I ended to this, but while it is working fine in the front end, this is causing PHP errors in the CP :

```
<?php

return array(
    'toEmail'  => array(
        ('firstemail@domain.com' ?: null),
        ('secondemail@domain.com' ?: null)
     )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to achieve this :

```
<?php

return array(
    'toEmail' => ('firstemail@domain.com,secondemail@domain.com' ?: null),
);
```

Comment: Well done Romain! - Please add the template tag to your answer, too

Comment: Thanks! There is no template tag related to recipients because they are dynamically set from the contactform.php config file.

Comment: Got it. Apologies, I misunderstood.